# dnn 7.4.2 build references missing

Tags: c#, build, .net-4.0, dotnetnuke-7

VS 2017 Pro - all .Net libraries installed

I need to use DNN version 7.4.2

I've downloaded the 7.4.2 version of the platform and am trying to compile the DNN_Platform solution.

When I do, a number of projects are missing references to

- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.Http.Formatting
- System.Web.Http
- System.Web.Http.WebHost
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Data.SqlServerCe

How can I get the solution to find these references and build? Do I need to compile something else first? The instructions for compiling the DNN solutions would be appreciated.

When I tried to use NuGet to get System.Net.Http it tells me:

> trying to install this package into a project that targets '.netframework,version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

When I do try to compile the solution I get errors suggesting remedies like:

> retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Net.Http".

But I want to build the source as it was downloaded.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that want to know, you need to install Asp.Net MVC 4 to resolve these reference issues.

You can find it in this link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30683)